# VSC Highlighting with Svelte

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte

I have been trying out Svelte for the last couple of days.
Everything is working fine, but then for some reason I get those weird highlighting bugs in VSC.
Whenever that happens, VSC is basically no longer useable (No IntelliSense, weird Highlighting, ...)

Has anyone of you experienced similar problems with Svelte?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you update your IDE, your plugins and svelte if you haven’t already, to use [the official Svelte plugin for VS code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode), to disable other plugins that may conflict with IntelliSense, and reloading VS Code. If the problem persists, it would be better to ask for help on [the plugin’s Github page](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools).